# Yii crud scaffolding - foreign key column name instead of id

Tags: yii, scaffolding

In phpmyadmin, i have created 2 tables within a mysql database.

for example - product table

```
tbl_product
id - int, pk, autoincrement
name - varchar 20
price - decimal
category_id - int, fk, notnull

tbl_category
id - int, pk, autoincrement
name - varchar(20)
```

from above, you can see that a product will contain a value for category_id.

I have auto generated the model for tbl_product in gii.

I am trying to create crud classes for tbl_product model, however when I do, I want to display tbl_category.name as a label and dropdown, not the id contained within tbl_product.category_id.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Answer (score 1):

In model (relations part):

```
'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'tbl_category', 'category_id')
```

In view, for example:

```
...isset($model->category) ? $model->category->name...
```

One thing to note - if you are going to show a lot of products with the related category name at once - you should use `$criteria->with = 'tbl_category'; $criteria->together = true'`. If you do that - yii will build query to get all needed data at once. Otherwise yii will ask database for the ctaegory name fore each post you display.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I recall it works that way.